# CQRS and DDD boundaries

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I've have a couple of questions to which I am not finding any exact answer. I've used CQRS before, but probably I was not using it properly.

Say that there are 5 services in the domain: Gateway, Sales, Payments, Credit and Warehouse, and that during the process of a user registering with the application, the front-end submits a few commands, the same front-end will then, once the user is registered, send a few other commands to create an order and apply for a credit.

Now, what I usually do is create a gateway, which receives all pubic commands, which are then validated, and if valid, are transformed into domain commands. I only use events to store data and if one service needs some action to be performed in other service, a domain command is sent directly from one service to the other. But I've seen in other systems that event handlers are used for more than store data. So my question is, what are the limits to what event handlers can do? And is it correct to send commands between services when a specific service requires that some other service performs an action or is it more correct to have the initial event raise and event and let the handler in the other service perform that action in the event handler. I am asking this because I've seen events like: INeedCreditAproved, when I was hoping to see a domain command like: ApprovedCredit.

Any input is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an important concept here - Sagas (Process Managers). You have a long-running workflow and it's better expressed centrally.

Sagas listen to events and emit commands. So OrderAccepted event will start a Saga, which then emit ApproveCredit and ReserveStock commands, to be sent to Credit and Warehouse services respectively. Saga can then listen to command success/failure events and compensate approprietely, like say emiting SendEmail command or whatever else.

Comment: +1 A Saga basically is a special type of event handler. It consumes events and emits commands, both inside a BC and across different BCs.

Comment: I use Sagas, just did not mention it. Probably my example was not be best one. But since you touch this, we have some weird stuff in our implementation of a Event driven SOA. In this specific case one of your services handles a user command, in this case the mobile phone, this same service then publishes one event: IMobilePhoneChanged, which does not carry the phone number. This events starts a saga, which also listen to a UpdatePhone, which is sent from the same service that raised the first event. Our architect has this idea that events should not carry data, so we have this big mess.

Comment: Events should cary all the data that makes the event. IF you have an OrderCreated event, while it shouldn't contain the Order object, it should contain the OrderId and other init data supplied (even the defaults, if they are configurable)

Comment: A domain event should carry all the data needed for that domain to be able to rebuild its state.

Answer (score 0):

One year ago I was sending commands like "send commands between services **by event handlers** when a specific service requires that some other service performs an action" but a stupid decision made by me switched to using events like you said "to have the initial event raise and event and let the handler in the other service perform that action in the event handler" and it worked at first. The most stupid decision I could make. Now I am switching back to sending commands from event handlers.

You can see that other people like Rinat do similar things with event ports/receptors and it is working for them, I think:

http://abdullin.com/journal/2012/7/22/bounded-context-is-a-team-working-together.html

http://abdullin.com/journal/2012/3/31/anatomy-of-distributed-system-a-la-lokad.html

Good luck

Comment: But why did you revert to what you were doing before? What sort of problems did you ran into? What I find hard to know is where the boundaries for the event handlers  finish. Some say that the handlers cannot change any state, but what if I do? I also send commands from event handlers but there seems to be way to many different opinions on this.